# How do I assign draggable attribute to all instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am sure this is a simple question, but I am very new to using jquery, so please excuse me.

I am trying to write a function that will "deal" 5 randomly selected images and allow 3 of them (of the user's choice) to be dropped into a div.

I have set up an array to handle the randomization of images and have figured out how to make the div droppable.  My first problem is that only the first image "dealt" is draggable.  It seems to me that I have an logic error in the `function dealCard()`...

```
function dealCard(i) {
    if (numberOfCardsInDeck == 0) return false;

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://debsiepalmer.com/images/companions/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".jpg";
    img.id = "drag"
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    $('#drag').draggable();
    removeCard(i);
}

function removeCard(c)
{

    for (j=c; j <= numberOfCardsInDeck - 2; j++)
    {
        cardsInDeck[j] = cardsInDeck[j+1];
    }
    numberOfCardsInDeck--;
    numberOfCardsInDeck--;
    numberOfCardsInDeck--;
}
```

...For the life of me, I can't figure out why it doesn't reassign the draggable attribute to the rest of the images.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My fiddle is:  http://jsfiddle.net/LEHbc/22/

Comment: save yourself a bunch of typing using syntax `cardsindeck=['Ace',Grace','Foo','bar']`

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, but I tend to get lost after the first 20 of them.  It's more typing, but it's a little easier for me to keep track of which names I've included this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a little more of jquery's functionality to help you out and like @Kazimeiras said a `class` attribute and not an `id`.

```
function dealCard(i) {
    if (numberOfCardsInDeck == 0) return false;
    var $img = $("<img src='http://debsiepalmer.com/images/companions/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".jpg' class='drag' />");
    $("body").append($img);
    $('.drag').draggable();
    removeCard(i);
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LEHbc/23/

Comment: You're a saint!  I can't tell you how long I was beating my head against the wall trying to figure that out.  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are using an element id to make the elements draggable. After you add a second element, there is more than one element with id="drag", thus the draggable is applied only to the first one encountered in the DOM.
Using a class in this case would be preferable.

Comment: That's what I thought would do the trick! But like I said I'm very new to this and have very little clue how to implement my ideas.  Setting an ID was something I could at least figure out how to pull off. Thanks for the help!